# Lost ability to drag files/folders to a network folder pinned in Quick Access - how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

Some time ago I lost the ability to drag files/folders to a network folder pinned in Quick Access - how to fix this?

Destination folder is located on a Windows XP machine, so that might have something to do with it.

I also have another folder located on a Sun OS machine - dragging files to that in Quick Access panel never worked on Win 10 from the start however.

System is Windows 10 Pro, build: 19042.1052
I can reproduce this bug on 3 different PCs with Windows 10 Pro.

Tried the same in Windows 7 with Favourites panel - works just fine there.

Comment: Have you tried to delete and recreate the Quick Access icon?

Comment: yes, it didn't change anything

Comment: You could signal the regression via the Feedback Hub, but it seems like you would need to find another way or method.